# Inserir div dinamicamente no html com js

Tags: javascript, html

É o seguinte, tenho o javascript abaixo e preciso inserir uma div dinamicamente após a oitava tag de quebra de linha (br) no meu texto. O código abaixo parece funcionar perfeitamente, mas não consigo fazê-lo funcionar no meu blogger.

```js
var newImage = document.createElement('p');
var img = document.createElement('div'); 
img.innerHTML = '<img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-nCxwwr5kcUM/WM7z-Gqi2FI/AAAAAAAAd2g/e30MQRv-EoUDwDIsAZyzCa0VqoaSPd6PQCK4B/s1600/ph-turismo.gif"/>';
newImage.appendChild(img);                    

var image = document.getElementById("myText");    
image.insertBefore(newImage, image.childNodes[8]);
```

```html
<div id="myText">
Na noite deste sábado (8), policiais do Batalhão Especilizado de Policiamento do Interior (BEPI) realizaram uma operação em Cabrobó, no Sertão Central pernambucano, para cumprir o mandado de prisão e capturar Mácio Ferreira de Moraes, conhecido como "Vela". Houve troca de tiros durante a ação, o suspeito foi baleado e levado ao hospital do municípío, mas não resistiu e morreu.
<br />
<br />
<div style="display: inline; float: left; margin-right: 15px;">
<!-- Bd.Ad TAG - Formato Banner Arroba - Website http://www.belmontediario.com.br -->
<div id="bdads_post"></div>
<!-- Fim da Bd.Ad TAG --></div>
"Vela" seria o explosivista e líder de uma quadrilha de assalto a banco e protagonizou vários roubos pelo interior: Águas Belas (dezembro de 2016), Buíque (janeiro de 2017), Missão Velha-CE (março de 2017), Ipubi (março de 2017). O suspeito, desde 2015, era fugitivo da cadeia de Belém do São Fancisco, aonde estava por responder pelo crime de homicídio. Ele também tinha um mandado de prisão por assalto a carro-forte.
<br />
<br />
O criminoso foi encontrado na fazenda Santa Cruz, em Cabrobó. A polícia chegou ao local e deu voz de prisão, quando Mácio de Moraes sacou duas pistolas de uso restrito (.40 e 90mm) e reagiu. Ele foi baleado, chegou a ser socorrido e levado ao hospital, aonde morreu.
<br />
<br />
Os materiais apreendidos e a ocorrência foram conduzidos à Delegacia de Polícia Civil de Floresta. No local, uma equipe de Força Tarefa de Repressão aos Assaltos a Banco e Carros Fortes deu prosseguimento às ações de polícia judiciária.
<br />
<br />
</div>
```

Comment: E qual o erro que acontece no blogger? Já tentou inspecionar se encontrou o elemento **img**? No blogger contém o mesmo número de tags `br` que você espera?

Comment: Olá, Ricardo, obrigado pela atenção! No Blogger, o código não funciona de jeito nenhum e na inspeção o elemento não aparece. Obs estou utilizando a biblioteca jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js. Sobre a quantidade de tags, dentro da div id "myText", tenho quantidade superior a pretendida. A idéia do código é que o elemento apareça entre os parágrafos dinamicamente e automaticamente em todos os posts do meu blogger. Tipo os sistemas ADs que tem nos grandes portais.